# Has anyone implemented a solution using UDP jumbograms?

Tags: network-programming, udp

I've recently learned about jumbograms (UDP packets > 65k - IPv6 only). Although I have no requirement to use them I thought I'd dig around and see how people had done anything clever.

I was surprised to find very little other than technical documentation protocol.

So has anyone used them and if so how?

Are they less reliable than UDP because they're larger?

Which language / software / hardware supported them?

What was your experience?

Cheers

Comment: Jumbograms are any datagram > MTU size, the maximum size for IPv4 is 64KB.  You have to be explicit to mention IPv6 jumbograms with the "jumbo payload" option in the header for packets 64KB to 4GB.

Comment: Jumbograms are IPv6 datagrams with the jumbo payload option. Datagrams > MTU are just datagrams that are too big, unless they are jumbos.

Comment: The connection with design patterns and architecture escapes me.

Comment: I added it because it is a transport layer which is a key architecture point when designing how your data moves from system to system. I'm not precious about it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux includes support as there is a vulnerability logged against it:

> **Systems affected**
>
> Linux Linux Kernel: 2.6.21, Linux Linux Kernel: 2.6.20, Linux Linux
>   Kernel: 2.6.2, Linux Kernel: 2.6.2 rc3, Linux Kernel: 2.6.2 rc2, Linux
>   Kernel: 2.6.2 rc1, Linux Linux Kernel: 2.6.20.1, Linux Linux Kernel:
>   2.6.20.10, Linux Linux Kernel: 2.6.20.11, Linux Linux Kernel: 2.6.20.12, Linux Linux Kernel: 2.6.20.13, Linux Linux Kernel: 2.6.20.14, Linux Linux Kernel: 2.6.20.2, Linux Linux Kernel: 2.6.20.3, Linux Linux Kernel: 2.6.20.4, Linux Linux Kernel: 2.6.20.5, Linux
>   Linux Kernel: 2.6.20.8, Linux Linux Kernel: 2.6.20.9, Linux Linux
>   Kernel: 2.6.21.1, Linux Kernel: 2.6.20 rc2, Linux Linux Kernel:
>   2.6.20.15, Linux Linux Kernel: 2.6.20.6, Linux Linux Kernel: 2.6.20.7, Linux Kernel: 2.6.21 git1, Linux Kernel: 2.6.21 git2, Linux Kernel:
>   2.6.21 git3, Linux Kernel: 2.6.21 git4, Linux Kernel: 2.6.21 git5, Linux Kernel: 2.6.21 git6, Linux Kernel: 2.6.21 git7

http://www.iss.net/security_center/reference/vuln/IPv6_Linux_Jumbogram_DoS.htm

Fragmented packets are inherently unreliable and DoS prone as resources have to be reserved until the full sequence is available to present to the consuming applications.

Note in IPv4 you could read individual fragments from the wire, IPv6 enforces the IP stack to only present fully reconstructed payloads.

Comment: UDP packets are read whole or not at all, in both Iv4 and IPv6.

Comment: @EJP `IPPROTO_RAW` can present IPv4 as fragments.