# How do you send a IPv6 jumbogram with winsock2?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming, winsock2

I've been wanting to experiment with datagram sizes > 64k but I'm stuck on this question. I can post code if it's helpful, but I updated my socket code to use IPv6 based on this excellent example:
http://cboard.cprogramming.com/networking-device-communication/67469-ipv6-multicast-example-code.html

After that I tried bumping up the send buffer size in hopes the framework would take care of any details. I did this:

```
int buffsize = 1024*1024;
auto err = setsockopt(socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, (char*)&buffsize, sizeof(buffsize));
```

No error was returned, and when I called getsockopt() on the sndbuf size it reported the size I set, but trying to send a datagram > 64k just resulted in the error that the size was too large.

My understanding from reading the docs is that to send a jumbogram, the length in the packet header is set to 0, and the payload size is placed in an IPv6 hop-by-hop options header. However, I can't see how to do that. I've experimented with just turning on the hop-by-hop options (I think?) by doing this:

```
int value(1);
auto err = setsockopt(mS, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_HOPOPTS, (char *)&value, sizeof(value));
```

but that just returns -1. When I call getsockopt it returns no error, but it changes the outgoing length value to 0, so I don't know what that means.

As part of looking into this, there are a couple SOs I came across that didn't get me to the answer:
[Has anyone implemented a solution using UDP jumbograms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498682/has-anyone-implemented-a-solution-using-udp-jumbograms)
[Does Winsock support IPv6 extension headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22933350/does-winsock-support-ipv6-extension-headers)

Comment: `IPV6_HOPOPTS` is not documented as a supported `IPPROTO_IPV6` option for `setsockopt()`.  However, it is documented as an available option for `WSASendMsg()` and `RIOSendEx()`.

Comment: Interesting, thanks much for the info! I wasn't aware of that API, investigating it. Thanks!